# Motor Oil In Coolant , No Coolant In Oil

Tags: ford, coolant

I have traces of motor oil in my radiator/coolant but none at all in my oil when I pull the dip stick. It's an older Ford Aerostar 1995 with the 4.0 V-6

Head gasket I would assume, or could it be the side of the radiator that cools the oil..? Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the oil on the transmission dipstick?

Comment: You should drain the oil to check for coolant in it...or taste it(don't).  Head gasket is the MOST likely source for contamination, but the "oil" could be from an integrated transmission cooler in your radiator.  Are you prepared to replace the head gaskets?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your radiator is busted from the inside, assuming your radiator has oil cooling lines going into it.